# Appending a structure to a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, append, structure

How do I append a structure of a class in a linked list. **The class will use a structure which will have the dvd title and its length. Each dvd will be an instance of this structure and will be stored in the linked list.** Also, the linked list shall have the data type of the structure

```
class DVD
{
private:
struct disc
  {
    int length;
    string title;
  }my_disc;

public:
// Constructor
DVD(int, string);

};
```

Linked list

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList1 
{
private:
// Declare a structure
struct discList
{
    T value;
    struct discList *next;  // To point to the next node
};

discList *head;     // List head pointer

public:
// Default Constructor
LinkedList1()
{ head = NULL; }


// Destructor
~LinkedList1();

// Linked list operations
void appendNode(T);
void insertNode(T);
void deleteNode(T);
void displayList() const;
};
```

Would it be

```
// Declare a DVD object
DVD dvd(105, "Spider Man"); // length and title

// Declare a linked list object with the data type of the struct disc.
LinkedList1<DVD> movie; 
// or
LinkList1<DVD::my_disc> movie;

// and then append it
movie.appendNode(dvd)
```

If I removed the struct from `class DVD` and just put the data members `length` and `title` as private members then I know that `LinkedList1<DVD> movie;` would work to append the node. The struct is throwing me off. I don't understand "**the data type of the linked list should be the struct**". To me that seems like `LinkedList1<disc>movie;` since `disc` is the name of the struct. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand "the data type of the linked list should be the struct".

I don't understand where you got that from. I suspect that in this sentence struct and class are synonyms.

1. DVD and disc relation is not "DVD **is** disc", but "DVD **contains** instance of disc".
2. If "movies" has a type of LinkedList1, then movies.appendNode(spiderman) requires spiderman to be of type DVD (or one that can be implicitly converted to DVD).
3. And I see no problem in doing so. In fact, that's how it's usually done, and what DVD has inside is only DVD class problem.

Comment: Those were my instructions from my instructor but I figured it out.

Comment: "the data type of the linked list should be the struct" translates to "the template parameter will be specialized to `DVD`", where "the data type" was used as a synonym for "the list nodes' content type" and "the struct" was used as a synonym for the specific struct `DVD` defined in the assignment text. A great reminder that precise wording is essential when teaching (especially) beginners.